# TS Error w/ Firebase [Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Auth'.] RecaptchaVerifier Initialization in Next.js Project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js project using Firebase for authentication, and I'm trying to implement phone number sign-in with reCAPTCHA. However, I'm encountering a TypeScript error when trying to initialize the RecaptchaVerifier.

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Auth'.`

This error occurs at the line where I instantiate the RecaptchaVerifier:

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    recaptchaVerifier?: RecaptchaVerifier;
    confirmationResult?: ConfirmationResult;
  }
}

const setupRecaptcha = () => {
  window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
    'recaptcha-container',  // ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
    {
      'size': 'invisible',
      'callback': (response: any) => {
        // Handle the reCAPTCHA response
      }
    },
    auth  // Firebase Auth instance
  );
  window.recaptchaVerifier.render();
};
```

I'm using Next.js with TypeScript.
Firebase is set up and imported correctly in the project.
The auth variable is imported from my Firebase utils file, which is initialized with `getAuth(firebaseApp)`.

Firebase Utils Import:

`import { auth, RecaptchaVerifier } from '@/utils/firebase';`

How can I resolve this TypeScript error and correctly initialize the RecaptchaVerifier in my Next.js project? Am I missing something in the way Firebase Auth should be passed to the RecaptchaVerifier constructor?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

I've checked to ensure that the auth variable is correctly imported and is an instance of Firebase Auth.
I tried logging auth to the console before initializing RecaptchaVerifier, but I did not see it in the browser console.
I searched for similar issues online but could not find anything in the same vein as this particular setup.